# Sharepoint installation in a farm

Tags: 2013, installation, server-farm, farm-solution

I have been looking for a guide or another place where there is explanation about how to install sharepoint. I have gone through a lot ow websites and I haven't found useful any of them. I am trying to make an application farm. I will use 3 servers. I already have an active directory. The most important part that I am trying to understand is the service accounts and how to work with them. The part of installation doesn't look tough, but the server configuration and farm configuration seems very difficult to grasp.

Comment: Are you sure you have taken a good look? There are great instructions and explanations on every step on Technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: These aren't hard too find.  [Microsoft Test Lab Guide for Three-Tiered farm](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30386) (SQL Server, App Server, WFE)

Comment: Service accounts example - http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=391

Comment: I have already checked all of the links, 
I will re read all of those info , maybe I have not understand any aprt properly. Thank you for your comments

Comment: Victory lies in preparation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of material available online about how to install as some already mentioned.

Deploying SharePoint farm consist two parts( this my theory). I am counting architecture part.

- Installation of SharePoint
- Configuration of SharePoint.

**Installation of SharePoint:** during this part you have to deal couple of things.

- [Hardware & Software Requriements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#reqOtherCap)
- [Pre-requisite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section7)
- [Services Accounts(](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html)
- installation Media( download from MSDN or VL or trial)
- [Install the SQL Server](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/installation-of-microsoft-sql-server.html)
- Method to install the sharepoint, [PowerShell](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) or [manual](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14209.sharepoint-2013-installation-step-by-step.aspx)

**Configuration of SharePoint:** In this part you have to cofnigure the Farm and other services application. Your Services account play role here.

- [Run Config wizard on 1st server](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/install-and-configure-sharepoint-server.html) in farm(usually the server which host Central Admin), at the end you will see a config db and central admin configured.
- Run Cofnig wizard on other servers one by one in order to join them existing farm.at the end all servers are part of farm and you can check them on the central admin
- Now you have to Confgured the all the required services application one by one i.e [User Profile](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/configure-user-profile-service.html), [Search](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/configure-search-service-application-on.html), [Managed Metadata](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/configure-managed-metadata-service.html) etc
- [Create Web Application & site collections](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/create-web-application-on-sharepoint.html), setting the authentication(Windows, ADFS, FBA etc)
- Any custom soultion or 3rd party tool integration. otherwise you all set.

Comment: nice list, 
I will go through it